# How to use a variable as an object's name: Python

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

I want to use a variable to access an attribute of an object created by a class, but Python uses the variable's name as a the object's name and not the name stored in the variable.

```
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

white = (255,255,255).

A1 = button(white, 50, 50, 20, 20, text='Hello World')


var = "A1"

print(var.text)
```

And when I run it:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Is there any way to use the information inside `var` as the object name when calling `var.text`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: Variable names are for the benefit of the coder, not the code itself. If your code needs a variable name, it means you should be using a `dict`.

Comment: should be avoided - but `print(eval(var).text)` also works.

Comment: Any time you think `Variable variables` think `dict` (or in other languages, associative arrays). Any other way of implementing this with workarounds or ghastly `php`-like nonsense is going to cause a mess and possibly your life when the next developer sees your code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

white = (255,255,255)

A1 = button(white, 50, 50, 20, 20, text='Hello World')


var = "A1"

print(locals()[var].text)
```

Comment: But is is surely better to use dictionaries.